# DDR4 differential pair routing guideline

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, differential, ddr

I have a question about the DDR4 trace routing on the server main board.

For clock and DQS signals, are they both considered differential signals?

I checked the Intel PDG; it shows that two specs for the impedance control on these signals.

In one table, it specifies the single-ended impedance spec.
In another table, it defines the trace spacing between P/N trace. Does anyone know why the spec defines the single-ended impedance for the differential pair?
Why not just define the differential impedance?

I also saw a spec for clock and DQS in another layout guideline. It says that the trace of these signals should be routed as a "pseudo differential pair", 
which means that we should first consider one trace as single-ended (here the spec defines 50 Ohm), and then try to meet the spacing as in the spec.

Again, why should we define the single-ended impedance for a differential pair?

Comment: Probably something to do with termination < hand waving / >

Answer (score 2):

DDR4 uses POD (Pseudo Open Drain, see picture below) signaling with:

- strong LOW level (0) = high power consumption,
- weaker HIGH level (1) = low (near to zero) power consumption.

> [image: DDR4 – Pseudo Open Drain]
>
> (example from Micron's TN-40-40, Figure 11)

To save power, the **paired** signals DQS_t and DQS_c are both kept HIGH during bus idles and commands issuing. Therefore, during such times the paired signals act as single-ended lines.

To transfer data, the paired signals DQS_t and DQS_c are pre-driven oppositely during a READ/WRITE preamble, then changed oppositely during data transmission cycles, and then post-driven again oppositely and then both HI during a READ/WRITE postamble (see picture below). Therefore, during such times the paired signals act as a differential line.

> [image: preamble and postamble]
>
> (example from JEDEC Standard No. 79-4, Section 4.21.2)

Based on this, DDR4 paired signals should be routed so complex: each signal of a pair should be routed as a single-ended, controlled-impedance transmission line as well as the whole pair should be routed as a differential, controlled-impedance transmission line.

---

P.S. Strongly speaking, JEDEC Standard for DDR4 does not introduce DQS's clearly as "differential pairs", instead, it states the following in short (that "in full" is described in it later):

> The data strobe DQS_t, DQSL_t and DQSU_t are paired with differential signals DQS_c, DQSL_c, and DQSU_c, respectively, *to provide differential pair signaling to the system during reads and writes*. DDR4 SDRAM supports differential data strobe only and does not support single-ended.
>
> (text from JEDEC Standard No. 79-4, Section 2.6)

Compare that with the introduction of CK's signals in the same document:

> CK_t and CK_c are differential clock inputs. All address and control input signals are sampled on the crossing of the positive edge of CK_t and negative edge of CK_c.
>
> (text from JEDEC Standard No. 79-4, Section 2.6)